# universal types deduction scott meyers

Tags: c++, c++11, effective-c++, forwarding-reference

I am reading Effective modern C++ by Scott Meyers

For universal references that are function parameters, the initializer is provided at the call site.

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& param);   // param is a  universal reference.

Widget w;
f(w)

f(std::move(w));


template<typename T>
void f(std::vector<T>&& param);  // param is an rvalue reference
```

For reference to be universal, type deduction is necessary, but it is not sufficient. The form of the reference declaration must also be correct, and that from is quite constrained. It must be precisely "`T&&`".

When f is invoked, the type `T` will be deduced (unless the caller explicitly specifies it, an edge case we'll not concern ourselves with). But the form of param's type declaration isn't "`T&&`", it's "`std::vector<T>&&`". That rules out the possibility that param is a universal reference. param is therefore an rvalue reference, something your compilers will be happy to confirm for you if you try to pass an lvalue to `f`

```
std::vector<int> v;
f(v); // error! can't bind lvalue to rvalue reference.
```

In above I have following question

1. What does author mean by "unless the caller explicitly specifies it, an edge case we'll not concern ourselves with " ? Request to provide an example what is edge case author is mentioning that caller explicitly specifies

Comment: *What does author mean by "unless the caller...* - `f<int>(w)`

Comment: The term has later been changed to [Forwarding Reference](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4164.pdf)

Comment: @amit is there is difference in type deduction if user specifies the type

Comment: There is no type deduction when type is explicitly specified

Answer (score 1):

The author is referring to the end user explicitly specifying the type parameter in the call to `f`:

```
f<Widget>(w);
```